# How to dynamically display parsed contents of XML on UITableView using RaptureXML and AFNetworking?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, afnetworking

I'm using `RaptureXML` and the wrapper `AFRaptureXMLRequestOperation` that integrates `AFNetworking` and `RaptureXML`.

The code below is working fine. All is well downloading, parsing and displaying the contents in an `UITableView`.

While I make the download and parsing in the background I update the `UITableView` on the `Main Thread`, **asynchronously**.

**The only problem is that the Contents of the UITableView only display after all the elements of the XML have been parsed and inserted in the appropriate `NSMutableArrays`, which sometimes takes a while.**

**My question**:

Is there a way to ***dynamically*** display the contents of the `UITableView` while they are being downloaded and parsed and the `NSMutableArrays` are being filled with data, like the examples that use `JASON` files from Twitter?

There is the code:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

       [self downloadParsePlayListXML];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
});

- (void)downloadParsePlayListXML {

NSString *url = @"http://example.net/playlist/xmlfiles/playlist.xml";
AFRaptureXMLRequestOperation *operation = [AFRaptureXMLRequestOperation XMLParserRequestOperationWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, RXMLElement *XMLElement) {

    [XMLElement iterateWithRootXPath:@"//program" usingBlock: ^(RXMLElement *program) {

        [self.programs addObject:[program attribute:@"name"]];
        [self.speakers addObject:[program child:@"speaker"].text];


    }];
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, RXMLElement *XMLElement) {
    // Handle Error
}];

[operation start];
```

}

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not able to test this until later today but I'll take a stab at it.  Note: I'm unfamiliar with RaptureXML.

First, see this post a few days ago about parsing the XML.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/16047964/1710611

Then, during parsing, each time it reaches the end of an element, you'll add it to your array (serving as the `UITableView` data source) and refresh the table.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"YOURTAG"]) {
        // finished getting the data in <YOURTAG>

        // do something now that you've got your data retrieved
        if (self.currentProperty) {
            [YOURDATASOURCEARRAY addObject:self.currentProperty];
            [tableView reloadData];
        }
    }  
}
```

Alternatively, you could also try replacing `[tableView reloadData]` with:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:YOURINDEXPATHARRAY withRowAnimation:YOURANIMATION];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: Thanks rog, I'll try it and let you know the results :-)

Comment: Good luck!  If there are any problems, I will help as best I can later this afternoon.  I hadn't considered dynamically updating it as it parses, so I am anxious to get home and attempt this in my apps too.

Comment: Great! If would please try the above code using RaptureXML, AFNetworking and AFRaptureXMLRequestOperation, three great libraries available on Github. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Apologies I didn't get back to you earlier.  I see you've marked the answer correct now - so you've solved your problem then?

Comment: Hey rog, thanks for getting back to me. Actually the solution was quite simple: I used your code, but first I populated the arrays with some dummy data, than I displayed the tableview first. I wasn't displaying because in a very first moment the array count was zero. It's not the most elegant solution, but it's working. If you happen to stumble on a better way to do this, please let me know, OK? Thanks a lot for helping me out :-)