# WSDL/XML parsing iOS objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, parsing, wsdl

I would like some help to parse this Response. I think it is WSDL and would like to check "Successfully Entered" string. Below is the code:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sch="http://example.com/reg/abc">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sch:LoginResponse>
         <sch:Status code=200>Successfully Entered</sch:Status>
         <sch:Message>[CDATA[Successfully Entered]]</sch:Message>
      </sch:LoginResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

EDIT: Below is the code I have implemented

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
   attributes: (NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    NSLog(@"START ELEMENT NAME ==> %@", elementName);
    if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"sch:Status"])
    {
        if(!soapResults)
        {
            soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        }
        elementFound = YES;
    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if( elementFound )
    {
        [soapResults appendString:string];
    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    NSLog(@"END ELEMENT NAME ==> %@", elementName);
    if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"sch:Status"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Found ==> %@", soapResults);
        [soapResults setString:@""];
        elementFound = FALSE;
    }
}
```

Print log shows upto `sch:LoginResponse` and does not come to element name `sch:Status`

Comment: tried `NSXMLParser` delegate methods to get into the element, but cannot get into the right one?

Comment: Why not? It's valid XML, what goes wrong during the parse?

Comment: i could get to the `sch:LoginResponse` elementName but then it doesn't match anything further. I think here I want to know how to print Input and Output message in WSDL. Please give me some example. THANKS

Comment: Here is an answer I wrote recently details how to use `NSXMLParser`.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16047964/1710611 Perhaps it may help you.

Comment: @rog I have implemented everything properly, just can't get the value inside `sch:Status`. It doesn't work after element name `sch:LoginResponse` is found.

Comment: You're looking for the `code=200` or `Successfully Entered`?

Comment: I am looking for `Successfully Entered`

Comment: Kindly edit your post and include your code you're using to parse.  I'll have a look.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30169/discussion-between-rog-and-samapple007)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per our chat, the problem is in the line:

```
<sch:Status code=200>Successfully Entered</sch:Status>
```

When `code=200` is changed to `code="200"` it parses correctly.

In other words, the XML is formatted incorrectly.  Attributes are supposed to have either a single (`'`) or double quotation (`"`) around the data.  (See [W3C XML recommendaiton](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/))

Additionally, the delegate detects the error `NSXMLParserAttributeNotStartedError` in the XML when left unchanged:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", parseError.localizedDescription);
}
```

If the XML *must* be retrieved this way, prior to parsing you can use this to surround it with quotation marks to make it valid, however you'd need to do it for each possible `code=###`:

```
yourXMLString = [yourXMLString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"code=200" withString:@"code=\"200\""];
```

Comment: Thank you, it help me a lot. You are a STAR @rog