# How Can I process all elements in xml?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xml, xml-parsing

I have an xml like this, but my XMLParser jumps 1-2 elements, and not process it. I think it works fine, but it not. What do i wrong?

Here is the xml, and i'd like to get the all item tag, and it's child elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<channel>
<title>News</title>
<description>News - Android</description>
<link>http://www.p.com</link>

   <item>
     <title>World Bench Press highlights - Day 2</title>
     <pubDate>Tue, 21 May 2013 00:00:00 +0000</pubDate>
     <imgLink>http://www.powerlifting-ipf.com/typo3temp/pics/1b7ecb3ac3.jpg</imgLink>
     <description>desc </description>
     <URL> some URL </URL>
   </item>
</channel>
</item>
</rss>
</channel>
```

Here is my XMLParser file, but i can't get any node, and it not put in my array. Not going to the 
`if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"item"])`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "XMLParser.h"

@implementation XMLParser
@synthesize tweets = _tweets;


NSMutableString *currentNodeContent;
NSMutableString *copy;
NSXMLParser     *parser;
Tweet           *currentTweet;
bool            isStatus=YES;

-(id) loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString
{
    _tweets         = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSURL *url      = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData  *data   = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    parser          = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];
    NSLog(@"0");
    return self;
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    NSLog(@"1");
    NSLog(@"currentnode %@",currentNodeContent);
    currentNodeContent = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:100];

    [currentNodeContent appendString:string];


}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    NSLog(@"2 Elementname : %@",elementname);
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"item"])
    {
        currentTweet = [Tweet alloc];
        isStatus = YES;

    }
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"title"])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",currentNodeContent);
        currentTweet.content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",currentTweet.content ,currentNodeContent];
    }
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    NSLog(@"ELEMENT: %@",elementname);

        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"description"])
        {

            currentTweet.description = currentNodeContent;

        }

        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"pubDate"])
        {

            currentTweet.dateCreated = currentNodeContent;

        }
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"title"])
        {

            currentTweet.title = currentNodeContent;

        }

        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"imgLink"])
        {

            currentTweet.imgLink = currentNodeContent;

        }   

        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"URL"])
        {

            currentTweet.URL = currentNodeContent;

        }
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"item"])
        {
            NSLog(@"%@ elem:",currentNodeContent);
            [self.tweets addObject:currentTweet];       
            currentTweet = nil;
            currentNodeContent = nil;
        }
}
@end
```

Comment: What does the log output say if you never see an 'item' element?

Comment: The LOG: http://pastebin.com/deUdc5xv

Comment: in the xml there's 12 item tag

Comment: Before you create the parser, log: NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding);

Comment: in loadxmlbyurl method?

Comment: Yeah, check exactly what you've got to parse through.

Comment: Here is an answer I wrote in the past that is applicable to your question.  Check it out for full sample code.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16043833/how-do-i-make-a-label-load-content-located-on-a-website/16047964#16047964

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is wrong because you are reallocating your mutable string every time that the XML parser finds new characters. This means that if you get a string like @"Hello", and the strings gets parsed into two separated string @"He" and @"llo", just @"llo" gets put into the mutable string. The correct approach is to allocate a new mutable string every time that you find a new tag, not when you find new characters.

Not sure because I am not aware of the whole context, but I would try to edit your first two methods this way:

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    NSLog(@"1");
    NSLog(@"currentnode %@",currentNodeContent);
    [currentNodeContent appendString:string];
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    currentNodeContent= [NSMutableString new];
    NSLog(@"2 Elementname : %@",elementname);
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"item"])
    {
        currentTweet = [Tweet alloc];
        isStatus = YES;
    }
}
```

Let me know what result you get. I also recommend putting breakpoints into every method to see (in the case) why you get some particular strings instead of expected results.

**Edit**

As for the XML, I tried to check it with xmllint, and it some errors. The problem is with these two extra lines after closing the channel tag:

```
</item> <!-- Not needed -->
</rss>
</channel> <!-- Not needed -->
```

Comment: unfortunately not, but i think the problem is in the xml file

Comment: Yes, I tried to check the file with xmllint. Indeed the XML isn't correct ( see the edited answer :-) ).

Answer (score 0):

You have one  between  and . Maybe that tag could be messing the parse procedure, try deleting it

Comment: I wrote that from my iphone and the XML tags have disappeared. I wrote that you had one </item> between </channel> and </rss>. Just to clarify the strange answer! :P